# Google Cloud Python Function suddenly throws TypeError msg

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, typeerror

I’m a Google Cloud Function user. I have a python function that can be run successfully. However, after I copied it to a new function name and tried to run it, I got the error msg below:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Which is very strange because I didn’t change anything and the old function is still able to be run successfully.

I looked into my codes and I found that the error message is caused from the code below:

```
leverage = binance.set_leverage(symbol,new_leverage,{})
```

I don’t know whether I’ve done anything wrong. Because when I tried to run it in my local machine by using Function Framework, everything is fine no error msg pop up.

Hope you can help me resolve this issue. Thank you.

**[Full Codes]**

```
import ccxt

binance = ccxt.binanceusdm({
    'apiKey': 'XXX',
    'secret': 'YYY',
})

def trade_crypto(request):
    try:
        TradingView = request.get_json()
        symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
        new_leverage = 99
        leverage = binance.set_leverage(symbol,new_leverage,{})
    
    except Exception as e:
        return{
            'Error':str(e)
        }
    return{
        'status':'success'
    }
```

Comment: You must find the correct code line. The error message/stack trace will show you. The error is caused by a **less-than** comparison between a string and an integer. Since your question does not show the problem code ... we cannot help you.

Comment: Are you querying an API and then compare the result? If the API spec has changed, it can cause your issue

Comment: Yes, I'm using API. I've just added my codes, please see them above. As I posted, I don't know why the exact same codes (but copied/saved to a different function name) cannot be run from Cloud Function now. But it is very strange that I can run it in my local machine successfully. Does this mean that there is a problem from Cloud Function side? Now, I am not sure where or what I should look to resolve this issue.

Comment: The execution must be consistent between your local environment and your cloud functions. if not, you have a twist somewhere.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is what I thought. First, I think it is a problem on Google Cloud, so I run my function on AWS Cloud instead and I got the same error. This means that the problem was not from Google Cloud and I found that it was from API spec just like you said. CCXT API library must have changed something. So, I used the official API library from Binance instead and the problem solved! Thank you guys so much for helping me sorted this out.